# How to click on the button with text as Continue as per the html through python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click on the following button "Continue" using Selenium in Python.

```
<div class="sb-modal-section">
    <button class="sb-modal-button primary">Continue</button>
    <button class="sb-modal-button">Rules</button>
</div>
```

I am able to locate the button using many methods including:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.sb-modal-button.primary')
```

or

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sb-modal-button primary']")
```

which I know isn't supposed to work because of the space.

However,

```
x.click()
```

doesn't perform the continue action. I have tried implicit and explicit waits, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. It finds them both and can display x.text. But the click doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try JavaScript executor for clicking

Comment: Worked like a charm, @AnkurSingh. 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided it seems the element with text as **Continue** is within a *Modal Dialog Box* so you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sb-modal-section>button.sb-modal-button.primary"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sb-modal-section']//button[@class='sb-modal-button primary'][contains(.,'Continue')]"))).click()
  ```